# Categories is not working

Tags: categories, solspace-user

in user add on

```
<select name="category[]">
    {categories}
        {category_body}
            <option value="{category_id}">
                {category_name}
            </option>
        {/category_body}
    {/categories}
</select>
```

Adding category to user is not working. Categories are not displaying in select dropdown.

Comment: "in user add on" - which tag pair are you using within the add-on ({exp:user:users}?) - give more details of your tempate code, including parameters used. Have you checked you're not disabling categories and that the tag pair supports categories variable pair?

Comment: {exp:user:register}{/exp:user:register} i am using inside this tag pairs while registering

Comment: Have you tried specifying the category group {categories group_id="1|4"} and I assume you have categories set up? Also ensure that the member group the registration is assigned to has access to the channel that the categories are assigned to.

Comment: Yeah i tried that but issue is not that. I didn't select the categories in user module. Now it's working fine. Thank you Peter.